# OpenSSL and what encryption method to use

Tags: linux, macos, security, encryption, openssl

I am on OS X 10.8.3, savvy with a command-line and I want to use OpenSSL to start encrypting sensitive information on my MacBook Pro

I know that I can use openSSL in a syntax like:

`openssl enc -aes-256-ecb -in in.txt -out encrypted.txt`

Can anyone explain what encryption type to use and why?

Also, Can I paste in a string to that openSSL command and get back an encrypted string to store in a file? (say a password list). Store each password encrypted in the text file and then encrypt the entire file as well.

I also assume that one can encrypt one way, then encrypt a second time using a different method for added protection.

if I encrypt this on OS X I also assume that I could decrypt it on Linux.

Comment: For encrypting files most conveniently, [GPG](http://www.gnupg.org/) would definitely be recommended over OpenSSL.

Comment: Also, the second argument to `openssl` is not an "encryption type" but a subcommand, to tell it what kind of action to take. For example, manupulation of X.509 certificates, manipulation of keys, signing, encryption, certificate generation, message digest calculation, etc...

Comment: Go with AES.  It is widely supported.

Comment: @Zoredache There are 18 AES options offered by `openssl enc`: cbc, cfb, cfb1, cfb8, ecb and ofb, each in 128/192/256 bit.

Answer (score 2):

You need to pay attention to this points while crypting anything:

```
● Confidentiality
● Integrity
● Authenticity
● Non-repudiation
● Access control
● Difficulty compromise
```

Taking this as the base you shoud choose the method wich helps you the most. (Being an Asymetric cypher a great way of accommplish a lot of the above.[Use a private and a public key..])

Also [Here's](http://www.madboa.com/geek/gpg-quickstart/) the GPG QuickStart Guide.

In the symetric ways there is AES(128, 192, 256 bits) and DES(64 bit per block)

Check this part of [this](http://www.madboa.com/geek/openssl/#encrypt) OpenSSL Manual

As someone says above using `GPG` is a great Idea beacuse of the use of Assymetric Keys which is always safer than just Passwords in any access...

To get a list of Cipher methos you can use:

```
openssl list-cipher-commands
```

So for example an AES Cipher:

```
openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -salt -in file.txt -out file.enc
```

And to decrypt

```
openssl enc -d -aes-256-cbc -a -in file.enc
```

Still, you may have occasion to want to encrypt a file without having to build or use a key/certificate structure.

In the [link](http://www.madboa.com/geek/openssl/#encrypt) there is the `How do I base64-encode something?` part and the `How do I simply encrypt a file?` part. Hope this can help you

For more info Dive onto [Asymmetric key techniques](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography) and [Symmetric-key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric-key_algorithm)

Here's the RFC for [Determining Strengths For Public Keys Used For Exchanging Symmetric Keys](http://www.networksorcery.com/enp/rfc/rfc3766.txt)

Hope this helps. Remember Always to read the manual of what you use.

Comment: That is a great link. Reading it. When you run something like: `openssl passwd -1 MySecret` how do you take the resulting hash and get back the face you entered `MySecret` to begin with?

Comment: Normally its showed after you create the cypher. It is showed right after finishing the command. Check out [this page](http://conshell.net/wiki/index.php/OpenSSL_usage_tips_and_examples). Has some usefull tips about the hash you say.  And A Certificate looks like [this](http://www.mail-archive.com/openssl-dev@openssl.org/msg32109.html) if you open it when created..

Comment: Maybe I am still confused. If I have a txt file that contains a bunch of passwords and I want to replace the plan text passwords in the sheet with shadow style pasword so if someone get their hands on my sheet they dont just get plain text passwords. I would run something like the command in my first comment and get the result. I paste that result in my password sheet where the plain text password was. Later I want to know what the password for something is and I just have that shadow style string. How to I decrypt that so I know what my actual password is?

Comment: I think you are a little confused on the way that keys work... it would be unsafe to be able to decrypt any message, don't you think? .. thats why you must have the private and public key... but if you really need to be able to decrypt make sure you use a secure password, and check the gpg crypt method `gpg -c myfile`. I think [this](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-how-to-encrypt-and-decrypt-files-with-a-password.html) is what you want and will solve the problem you say